# jQuery Sortable using mouseup, mousedown

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

i trying to use the [jQuery Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) and works :)

so i found [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/W7tvD/1399/) a way to do using mousedown and mouseup to take off the button, works but the count of the list is wrong, for example, i have 4 items in my list but when i move one, only 3 as reordered

the complete code this:

```
$(function() {

        var isDragging = false;
        $("#sortable").mousedown(function() {
            isDragging = false;
        })
        $("#sortable").mousemove(function () {
            isDragging = true;
        })
        $("#sortable").mouseup(function () {
            var order = $("#sortable").sortable('serialize');

            var r = $("#sortable").sortable("toArray");
            var a = $("#sortable").sortable("serialize", {
                attribute: "id"
            });
            console.log(r, a);
            $.ajax({
                data: order,
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'salvar.php', // save.php - file with database update
                success: function (order) {

                },
            });
            var wasDragging = isDragging;
            isDragging = false;
            if (!wasDragging) {
                $("#throbble").toggle();
            }
        });
    });
```

Html:

```
<ul id="sortable">
<li class="ui-state-default" id="item-1">1</li>
<li class="ui-state-default" id="item-2">2</li>
<li class="ui-state-default" id="item-3">3</li>
<li class="ui-state-default" id="item-4">4</li>
```

Running code:
[Running Code](https://jsfiddle.net/iwacham/tjv54qqa/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the [events](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update) sortable itself provides. Way easier then trying to implement that yourself:

```
$('#sortable').on('sortupdate', function() {
    // Send to server
});
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/petervanderwal/tjv54qqa/1/)